# How to identify file upload input used in C# razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, file-upload

I have two file uploads in my form. In my razor C# code, how do I identify which form upload the uploaded file belongs to? I would like to know if the first form control was used or the second. Based on that, I need to decide what to do with the file uploaded.

Other form fields can be identified using `Request.Form["name"]`

Here is my form in razor page.

```
 <form class="theform" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                              <div class="fileUpload">
                                @FileUpload.GetHtml(
                                initialNumberOfFiles: 1,
                                allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false,
                                includeFormTag: false,
                                uploadText: "Upload")
                            </div>
                            <div class="fileUpload">
                                @FileUpload.GetHtml(
                                initialNumberOfFiles: 1,
                                allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false,
                                includeFormTag: false,
                                uploadText: "Upload")
                            </div>
  <button type="submit" formaction="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">submit</button>
    </form>
```

C# code after form submit

```
if (IsPost){
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    var uploadedFile = Request.Files[i];
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer below code,

In HTML,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>First File<sup>*</sup></label>
    <input type="file" id="first-file" name="first-file" value="Upload"  required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Second File<sup>*</sup></label>
    <input type="file" id="second-file" name="second-file" value="Upload"  required />
</div>
```

In C#

```
var httpPostedFiles = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;     
if (httpPostedFiles.Count > 0)
     {
          var FirstFile= httpPostedFiles["first-file"]
          var SecondFile = httpPostedFiles["second-file"]
     }
```

Comment: how does it work for multiple number of files? if each form upload support multiple file upload, how does it work then?

Comment: you mean if I use `multiple` attribute in the input tag, right?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this blog answers this question:

http://www.mikepope.com/blog/AddComment.aspx?blogid=2329

> People sometimes ask whether there's a way to get additional information about the upload. For example, if you have two FileUpload helpers on a page, can you tell which one submitted the file?
>
> Yes. Specify the helper this way:

```
<form method="post" name="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles: 1,
    allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false,
        includeFormTag: false,
        uploadText: "Upload2",
        name: "Upload2"
    )
    <input type="submit" name="buttonUpload2" value="Upload File 2" />
</form>
```